# Open/edit a .txt file located in application bundle with NSTextView object

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I would like to add an `NSTextView` object to my app and add an action that opens a .txt file located in the app bundle in the textView. Also - I would like to have the option to edit and save the edited doc without renaming it. So standard save, not save as.

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Just realized this is about NSTextView and not UITextView, so I deleted my answer...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use NSString to load the file and put it in your text view:

```
NSTextView *textView; //your NSTextView object
NSError *err = nil;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EditableFile" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
if(!contents) {
    //handle error
}
[textView setString:contents];
```

Saving is just the opposite. Get the string and write it to the file:

```
NSTextView *textView; //your NSTextView object
NSError *err = nil;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EditableFile" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *contents = [textView string];
if(![contents writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err]) {
    //handle error
}
```

Comment: I commented out NSTextView *textView in the load file method. That works fine. I can't get Save to work ...

Comment: To expand this a bit - as far as saving, what if there are multiple files in the bundle? The save method needs to save whatever the contents of the textView. Any ideas?

Comment: @Paul The NSTextView *textView is just a reminder to get the textView. What do you mean "What if there are multiple files in the bundle?" The code saves it to the same place it loaded from.

Comment: Yes I know ;) My mistake. As far as the multiple files - there are a total of 9 files in the bundle that I need to be able to open. I replaced @"EditableFile" with specific file names to open them. That works fine. As far as the save/write method - I need it to save whatever edit is made on whatever file string happens to be in the textView at any given time. Does that make sense? Thanks.

Comment: @Paul Then you will have to save the current path somewhere. An instance variable on the object loading and saving would work fine. Just set it in the loading method and use it in the saving method instead of loading the path again.